# API WebService Not responding anything

Tags: c#, api, web-services

This is basically my first API handling with C#, so I read and tried to create so I can handle the JSON, but I ain't getting any response, tried to display it in a label text, but I am not getting any error nor any response.

It is supposed to show the JSON in a label with answer with basic auth, so then, I can handle it, because I have been able to see the JSON if I log via POSTMAN, but if I run the code, all I see is nothing, even tho it is wrapped in a string.

```
public partial class callUni : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strResponse = string.Empty;
            strResponse = makeRequest();
            answer.Text = strResponse;
    }

    public string makeRequest()
    {
        string strRequest = string.Empty;
        try
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://unicard-api.asf.edu.mx:8443/api/Acessos/Entradas");
            request.Credentials = GetCredential();
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.Method = httpMethod.ToString();
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("error code = " + response.StatusCode);
                }
                //Vamos a procesar el JSON que viene de UNICARD
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            strRequest = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { };
        return strRequest;
    }

    private CredentialCache GetCredential()
    {
        string url = @"https://unicard-api.asf.edu.mx:8443/api/Acessos/Entradas";
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
        credentialCache.Add(new System.Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxxxx"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxxx"]));
        return credentialCache;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "I am not getting any error nor any response.", but I think you are getting an error, but your line here is hiding it from you:

```
catch (Exception e) { };
```

Try either logging or displaying e.ToString() inside the catch block then investigating from there.

As a sidenote, Microsoft explicitly says not to throw ApplicationException. Either find a more relevant Exception class to use or throw Exception. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Remarks

Comment: Absolutely right... Got it to connect to a non basic authenticated!